# How to observe key path on 'Any' object in Swift 4

Tags: swift, macos, key-value-observing, swift4

I'm using the new Swift 4 KVO and KeyPath APIs to observe changes on an object. Specifically I'm trying to observe something on the selection object of an `NSArrayController`. The problem is the `selection` is of type `Any` and that seems to be at odds with generating the required keypath, since the compiler doesn't know of any properties on an object of type `Any`.

The property's name is `assetPointHeight`. And my code looks like this:

```
var observation: NSKeyValueObservation?

observation = arrayController.observe(
    #keyPath(NSArrayController.selection.assetPointHeight),
    options: [.new],
    changeHandler: { [weak self] (_, _) in
        self?.updateLabel()
    }
)
```

I get two compile errors:

> Generic parameter `Value` could not be inferred
>   Type 'Any' has no member 'assetPointHeight'

How can I achieve what I'm looking for here? Is there another way of generating this KeyPath?

Comment: I ran into the same problem. The solution was to use the traditional KVO way.

Comment: Found any way to make this work without using the traditional string-based KVO?

Answer (score 1):

I would not expect this to work because `assetPointHeight` isn’t a real property on `selection` (eg, it’s not defined anywhere in source code, it’s a virtual property created at runtime). I think what’s happening here is the Swift 4 version of `observe(...)` is trying to resolve that path to a static type and cannot, so it’s throwing an error. (Observing only works on `NSObject` subclasses, as well, so `Any` could never be observed.) So in this case you would have to use traditional string-based KVO, as “vadian” said.